# Continuous Login Sessions For Super Admins Across Multi-Site Network of Sites

Tags: admin, dashboard, multisite, authentication

I've looked around on WPSE, and WordPress.org and Google. Can't seem to find much information on this topic.

Is it possible to enable continuous login sessions across all WordPress Multi-Site linked domains for Super Admins only?

It's really quite a hassle to manage all the linked sites, and having to re-authenticate each time, and always entering the same information each time.

If anyone has input on this, whether it be good or bad feedback regarding my question, I would like to learn more information on this topic.

Comment: Did you ever get an solution figured out for this? Here we are five years later, and still not much out there about cross-site continuous login.